# Bash environment variable inherited by child without "export"

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I have the following script in ~/bin/ in order to override the default command for `gnome-terminal`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
XDG_CONFIG_HOME=~/.config/darkthemesettings /usr/bin/gnome-terminal
```

I am trying to make the `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` variable only get seen by gnome-terminal, but in terminal that appears, if I run any other program, the variable is also set in that program. Running `echo $XDG_CONFIG_HOME` from the terminal gives
    /home//.config/darkthemesettings

I understood that if one sets an environment variable without using `export`, that variable is only available in the script that sets it, not in any child processes. Am I incorrect? How can I achieve what I want here? Thanks

Comment: `VAR=value cmd`, on one line, exports the variable for the duration of that line. That's *what it does*. So of course it's still inherited by subprocesses.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `env` to unset the variable for the command run inside the terminal, like this:

```
XDG_CONFIG_HOME=~/.config/darkthemesettings gnome-terminal -x env -u XDG_CONFIG_HOME bash
```

The assignment `XDG_CONFIG_HOME=~/.config/darkthemesettings` before the command `gnome-terminal` sets the variable for the terminal. The terminal will run the arguments after the `-x` option as shell command. That shell command `bash` is prefixed by `env -u XDG_CONFIG_HOME` which unsets the variable in the environment for running `bash`.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is incorrect. Without `export` they are bash variables. `export` "promotes" them to environment variables.

You will need to have gnome-terminal run a script that unsets the variables before running the shell.

Comment: I see what you mean. What would be the best way to do that?